# How to modify a value of a struct within a function? [C]

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's see this code as an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct 
{
    int hp;
}Player;

void lessHp(Player a)
{
    printf("a.hp = %d\n", a.hp);
    (*Player) -> hp -= 1;
    printf("a.hp now = %d\n", a.hp);
}

int main()
{
    Player a;
    a.hp = 1;
    lessHp(a);
    printf("a.hp = %d\n", a.hp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, what this program prints is:

```
a.hp = 1
a.hp now = 0
a.hp = 1
```

But how can I make it so that the lessHp function would actually be able to substract 1 from that value? When trying to do it by reference it tells me to use ("->"), but I really, really don't know what that is (I've only used simple pointers, the only thing that I've handled with pointers is dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: pass a reference, not a copy

Comment: C passes arguments by value. When you give just a struct, it passes the value of the struct (a copy of it). Giving a pointer passes the _location_ of your original struct, so you can write modifications at that location.

Comment: What is this `(*Player) -> hp -= 1;`? This does not compile, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a pointer instead of passing a copy. (That is you should be editing original.) You can fix like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct 
{
    int hp;
} Player;

void lessHp(Player* a)
{
    printf("a.hp = %d\n", a->hp);
    a->hp -= 1;
    printf("a.hp now = %d\n", a->hp);
}

int main()
{
    Player a;
    a.hp = 1;
    lessHp(&a);
    printf("a.hp = %d\n", a.hp);
    return 0;
}
```

With an output of:

```
a.hp = 1
a.hp now = 0
a.hp = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of hassle.

Comment: @Yoakain opening a book in ten first pages takes less time, than wainting help from web

Comment: I read a lot before asking for help, did not find my answer + I needed it quick. Your advice could've been helpful otherwise.